# Inconsistent output: zip() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing the data structure and algo problems and I want to use the zip() function in my solution.

```
opening_paren = set('({[')
closing_paren = set(')}]')
matches = {(opening, closing) for opening, closing in zip(opening_paren, closing_paren)}
```

When I tested this code in the terminal I got this output:

```
>>> set([('(', ')'), ('{', ']'), ('[', '}')])
```

But Im expecting to get this answer:

```
Expected: >>> set([('(', ')'), ('{', '}'), ('[', ']')])
```

Than I tried to execute the same code in [pythontutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display) and it worked as expected.

Question: What am I doing wrong, that I'm not getting the expected result. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The order if sets is arbitrary

Comment: ... so use tuples or lists instead.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: And not just arbitrary: For strings, it'll change from run to run thanks to the hash salt. So working sometimes and failing at other times is *expected* on CPython.